# SharePoint Designer 2010 Approval Workflow Due Dates

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have an approval workflow created with impersonation steps. Is there a way to create an action where if an item is not approved in two days, the approval is re-routed back to the previous approver. That previous approver would have to re-approve the item.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the Approval setting, specifically in `"Change the behavior of a single task"`

[image]

At `"Change the behavior of a single task"`, there is step `When a Task Expires`. you can do the following:

- End Task Process.
- Assign the task to a specific person or `Workflow Context:Initiator`

[image]

```
Workflow Context:Initiator
```